# Getting a response back from ravesdk in ios

Tags: ios, swift

when i try to make transaction and its successful the response i get back is nill bellow is my code and error

```
func tranasctionSuccessful(flwRef: String?, responseData: [String : Any]?) {
    let dataDic = responseData as NSDictionary
    if(dataDic.get("status") == "success"){
        self.customerVerified(flutterWaveToken: "")
    }else{
        self.customerVerified(flutterWaveToken: "")
    }
}
```

here is the error x code gave me below

[String : Any]?' is not convertible to 'NSDictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the error means that the way you change [String:Any]? which is optional value to Dictionary is wrong.

Secondly, in Swift you should prefer to use Dictionary instead of NSDictionary (you can read this in docs) and response value of "status" is type Any you should cast it into String to compare with "success"

The full code with check nil value will be like this

```swift
func tranasctionSuccessful(flwRef: String?, responseData: [String : Any]?) {
    // check nil value
    if (responseData == nil) {
        return
    }
    
    let dataDic = responseData! as Dictionary // case optional value to non optional value
    let status = dataDic["status"] as! String? // be sure that status response value is String
    
    // check if not have status value
    if (status == nil) {
        return
    }
    
    if(status! == "success") {
       self.customerVerified(flutterWaveToken: "")
    } else {
       self.customerVerified(flutterWaveToken: "")
    }
}
```

If you be sure that response value is not nil && status is not nil you can shorten into this

```swift
func tranasctionSuccessful(flwRef: String?, responseData: [String : Any]?) {
    let dataDic = responseData! as Dictionary
    if(dataDic["status"] as! String == "success") {
        self.customerVerified(flutterWaveToken: "")
    } else {
        self.customerVerified(flutterWaveToken: "")
    }
}
```

More over: I think you should read about Dictionary and how to deal with response data from docs for further information. Apple provides us well document.

Comment: yes i got it, so now i want to get the value not a nil value, how will i get the value out of the dictionary.

Comment: Dear @AdeolaSegun, when it passes the nil value check, it always has the value. Just call the key from dictionary you will get the value. Example like above: dataDic["status"] means get value from key "status" in dictionary

Comment: the thing is the value is never a nil its either i get success or unsuccess, so if(dataDic["status"] as! String == "success") {
        self.customerVerified(flutterWaveToken: "")
    } else {
        self.customerVerified(flutterWaveToken: "")
    }     should pick what the value of status is

Comment: Dear @AdeolaSegun, so you just need to let value = calldataDic["status"] as! String and value here is the value of status

Comment: ["message": Charge Complete, "data": {
        "settlement_token" = "<null>";
        status = successful;
        txRef = 83171132192022;
        updatedAt = "2022-09-01T16:12:31.000Z";
        vbvrespcode = 00;
        vbvrespmessage = successful;
    };
}, "status": success]

Comment: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: In here because the response data you given above is not a valid one. You should check again for the valid JSON. Check the link below for valid json one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71500821/swift5-how-to-handle-this-json-response-into-swift-data-model